# What would be an example of a (either recursive or not) algorithm used to do long subtraction using stacks in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, stack

I asked this question before but in a more complicated way and I think maybe I wasn't being clear.

Imagine I have two stacks of integers that each represent one whole number, parsed from a String.  The first one out of each is the 1's place, the 2nd is the 10's place, third is 100's place, etc.  I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this because I feel like I need to do it recursively and recursive algorithms confuse me, especially in this case.  I appreciate any help.

```
int difference, z;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
  x = firstNum.pop();
  y = secondNum.pop();
  difference = x - y;
  if (difference < 0)
  {
    z = firstNum.pop();
    firstNum.push(z - 1);
    firstNum.push(x + 10);
  }
  else
  {
    result.push(difference);
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need some pointers on how to approach a long subtraction algorithm using stacks in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884203/need-some-pointers-on-how-to-approach-a-long-subtraction-algorithm-using-stacks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need recursion but you have an error.

```
int difference, z;
while (!firstNum.isEmpty ())
{
  x = firstNum.pop();
  y = 0;
  if (!secondNum.isEmpty ()) // account for the case when secondNum has less digits
    y = secondNum.pop();
  difference = x - y;
  if (difference < 0)
  {
    z = firstNum.pop();
    firstNum.push(z - 1);
    result.push(difference + 10); // fixed this line, since you want to push the
                                  // difference to the result
  }
  else
  {
    result.push(difference);
  }
}
```

Now, you should note that the digits in the `result` stack would be in reversed order. At the end of the subtraction, the most significant digit would be at the top of the stack.

Here's a complete method with hard coded sample input :

```
  public static void subtract ()
  {
    Stack<Integer> firstNum = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> secondNum = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> result = new Stack<Integer>();

    // firstNum == 3002
    firstNum.push (3);
    firstNum.push (0);
    firstNum.push (0);
    firstNum.push (2);

    // secondNum == 129
    secondNum.push (1);
    secondNum.push (2);
    secondNum.push (9);

    int difference, z;
    while (!firstNum.isEmpty ())
    {
      int x = firstNum.pop();
      int y = 0;
      if (!secondNum.isEmpty ())
        y = secondNum.pop();
      difference = x - y;
      if (difference < 0)
      {
        z = firstNum.pop();
        firstNum.push(z - 1);
        result.push(difference + 10);
      }
      else
      {
        result.push(difference);
      }
    }
    while (!result.isEmpty ())
      System.out.print (result.pop ());
    System.out.println ();
  }
```

Output

```
2873
```

Note that this method assumes the first number is higher than the second. Some handling should be added for the case of the first number being smaller.

Comment: The result stack is still not the correct answer, though.  Something else is missing and I can't quite put my finger on it.  I added a check to see if i is equal to the size of firstNum or secondNum and break accordingly, that way it doesn't attempt to pop off an empty stack.  With this algorith, when I subtract 129 from 3002, I get a stack of [12, 9] which is definitely wrong.

Comment: I got your updated changes and that's not quite working either.  I put some code before it to add preceding zeros to the String with less digits - in other words, 392 minus 53 would now be 392 minus 053.  That way each Stack has the same number of elements.  With this updated code, I tried subtracting 129 from 3002 and got 3782.  I think it's close to the right answer.

Comment: Hey thanks for all your help.  This set me on the right track.  Any idea of how to deal with the special case of a negative result?

Comment: @PeterGriffin You should probably add zeroes to the bottom of the two stacks to make them of equal length. Then, if your `if (difference < 0)` condition is true, check if the `firstNum` stack is empty. If it is this means the result is negative. In this case, the easiest solution is to restart the subtraction, this time subtracting firstNum from secondNum, and add a minus sign to the last digit of the result.